# How to override the back button / sipe functionality in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v6

I am trying to acheive overiding the back/swipe back functionality in react native.

If you land on a page and it has a param of previousScreen. Then this screen should be used to override the back functionality. Using navigation.navigate(previousScreen) to go to that screen.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

The code below I'm trying gives me a maximum call stack error when clicked, I think its due to the dependencies in my useEffect but not sure:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const handleBeforeRemove = e => {
      e.preventDefault();

      if (!previousScreen) {
        navigation.dispatch(e.data.action);
      } else {
        navigation.navigate(previousScreen);
      }
    };

    if (previousScreen) {
      const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener(
        'beforeRemove',
        handleBeforeRemove,
      );

      return unsubscribe;
    }
  }, [navigation, previousScreen]);
```

Tried like this also same error:

```
   const backAction = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (previousScreen) {
      navigation.navigate(previousScreen);
      return;
    }

    if (!previousScreen) {
      navigation.dispatch(e.data.action);
      return true;
    }

    return;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', backAction);
    return () => {
      navigation.removeListener('beforeRemove', backAction);
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: If previousScreen is the same as the actual previous screen in the stack, the result is the infinite loop.

Comment: Gotcha that makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using the useBackHandler hook or not.

Using useBackHandler hook:

Make sure to install `@react-native-community/hooks` to use the `useBackHandler` hook.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { useBackHandler } from '@react-native-community/hooks';

const YourPage = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  const previousScreen = route?.params?.previousScreen || '';

  const handleBackPress = () => {
    if (previousScreen !== '') {
      navigation.replace(previousScreen);
      return true;
    }
    // If previousScreen is empty, perform default back action
    return false;
  };

  useBackHandler(handleBackPress);

  if (previousScreen === '') {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>No specific back functionality available</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    // Your component's JSX
  );
};

export default YourPage;
```

Without using useBackHandler hook:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BackHandler, View, Text } from 'react-native';

const YourPage = ({route}) => {
  const previousScreen = route?.params?.previousScreen || '';

  const handleBackPress = () => {
      navigation.replace(previousScreen)
      return true;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (previousScreen !== '') {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackPress);
    }

    return () => {
      if (previousScreen !== '') {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackPress);
      }
    };
  }, [previousScreen]);

  return (
    // Your component's JSX
  );
};
```

Make sure to check https://github.com/react-native-community/hooks#usebackhandler if you decide to proceed if `useBackHandler`.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, ill test them asap!

For the second option:

canGoBack < where is this set to begin with?

Comment: I am sorry, you can ignore that, that value wont be needed. I updated the answer